# find label of a data point from an original dataset: a function

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this function which gets a datapoint (here all X1 to X16) from a dataset and find/read its label ( here 'class') from the original dataset provided as df_all:

```
def label_finder(df_all,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8,X9,X10,X11,X12,X13,
                                 X14,X15,X16):    
    y_new_data= df_all.loc[(df_all['X1'] == X1) 
                        & (df_all['X2'] == X2) 
                        & (df_all['X3'] == X3)
                        & (df_all['X4'] == X4)
                        & (df_all['X5'] == X5)
                        & (df_all['X6'] == X6)
                        & (df_all['X7'] == X7)
                        & (df_all['X8'] == X8)
                        & (df_all['X9'] == X9)
                        & (df_all['X10'] == X10)
                        & (df_all['X11'] == X11)
                        & (df_all['X12'] == X12)
                        & (df_all['X13'] == X13)
                        & (df_all['X14'] == X14) 
                        & (df_all['X15'] == X15)
                        & (df_all['X16'] == X16),'class']

    return y_new_data
```

the issue is that I don't want to write all those X1, X2,... Xn.

assume I have a dataset which has 60 features, then I need to write X1,X2, ...,X60!

How can I fix this function?

Comment: What is X1? A value, a boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
cols = ['X1', 'X2', ..., 'X60']

# or you can write col as
cols = ['X'+str(i) for i in range(1,61)]

def label_finder(df_all,x):    
    return df_all.loc[(df_all[cols] == x).all(axis=1),'class']

x = [X1, X2, ..., X60]
y_new_data = label_finder(df_all,x)
```

Comment: still in cols=['X1', 'X2', ..., 'X60'] I need to write X1 to X60.

Comment: how the function should be modified based on your suggestion?

Comment: I modified the answer to cover this case as well